# cURL error while excecute string

Tags: php, mysql

i have string like this

```
$string = "Hello, Bayu Cakra, you have got a new case, please check this URL <a href='https://try.this'>Open this URL</a>";
$encode = urlencode($string);
```

i want to insert that string to my cURL POST, but doesn't work, anyone can help me to this problem??

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode` doesn't mean a story will be encoded just fine. Give it just the url.

```
https://try.this?a=hello how are you doing today
```

That is something to urlencode and not a sentence with a url in it.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer, but i think i can insert method <a> for a button click on my query, because it use on my android API for messaging application

but, thanks for your answer, it really helpfully